# Change "UpdateOn"-Behavior after FormControl was created

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is it possible to change the UpdateOn-Behavior after it has been created? It seams like the property of the AbstractControl is readonly:

```
// Cannot assign to 'updateOn' because it is a read-only property.
this.form.get('field').updateOn = 'blur';
```

The form is created in a base class and right now I cannot controll the process of creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setControl to replace an existing control.

**component.ts**

```
  this.form.setControl('field',new FormControl('', {
    updateOn: 'blur'
  }));
```